# Adjective that simultaneously means fearless and hopeless?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective or a noun that simultaneously means fearless and hopeless.

A word ***x***, such that ***x*** = **fearless** + **hopeless**?

To elaborate, ***x*** is a feeling. I know I will die today and that its unavoidable, yet it only gives me energy to fight. So I continue on in a deranged fearlessness, abandoning myself to the endeavor. Having resigned myself to losing everything, and broken loose from any fear of loss.

Comment: What is x: a person, a situation, a pure quality ? What research did you do, what word did you come up with, did you even bother looking into a dictionnary of synonyms?

Comment: The question is clear. An adjective that means fearless and hopeless. I came up with essentially nothing. Its my opinion that there is not a word combining these two meanings, but I'm hoping someone has an idea. In German you could make a compound adjective by smashing them together, but English doesn't have that luxury.

Comment: @DiVangela - of course you can make a compound adjective in English. You say **fearless and hopeless**!

Comment: I mean one big phatass word, you cant say 'fearless-hopeless'. Well you could but its dissatisfying. Or perhaps a compound noun like "fearless-hopelessness".

Comment: It's a somewhat cliched observation that a person can be *fearless because they have **nothing to lose*** (whether because they don't value life, or have no expectation of surviving). But I doubt there's a single word term for it.

Comment: We English-speakers don't do that. We use many smaller rat-a-tat tat words like bullets from a machine gun. Its fun!  Throw in dozens of little Saxon words like ninjas to smite the reader!!!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - its usually called something like "the courage of desperation"

Comment: I think there actually *is* a word that means exactly this, but I'm not finding it. The closest my brain is getting is "fey", which doesn't actually mean anything even close, at least according to the dictionary, but I've seen it used to describe exactly that "well, since I ain't gonna survive anyway, might as well go out with a bang" attitude.

Comment: fey in that sense just means fated to die. It is up to the person if you resign, or fight bravely, or sing songs of defiance.

Comment: In fact, probably the sense the OP really wants is **fearless because of hopelessness**, a kind of last-stand mentality.

Comment: *Fearless* and *hopeless* are not parallel: the former describes an attitude, the latter describes a situation.

Comment: I think there's no single adjective that signifies this breaking loose from the fear of losing one's life.  "Resigned" doesn't capture the exhilaration of "breaking lose": one could be resigned and moribund. It's a state of mind where one steps outside oneself, and where one transcends the animal mandate for self-preservation.

Comment: A lover-of-lost-causes. Although since you provided a philosophicalish definition of a human, can't you just say a *human?*

Comment: @DiVangela  Why are all the best questions on this site closed? My idea is "dauntless"

Answer (score 1):

***Desperate*** implies being both fearless and hopeless in the right context. Because you can become fearless and reckless out of despair if you lose all your hope.

> - Having lost all hope; despairing.
> - careless of danger, as from despair; utterly reckless
>
> <sub>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/desperate</sub>

Comment: "Desperate people make decisions that are not in their best interest out of fear." [yourtango.com](http://www.yourtango.com/experts/melanie-gorman/feeling-desperate-change-your-mindset-improve-your-lovelife#.VGo662fg00o)

Answer (score 0):

brave: He is a brave man.

courageous, heroic, intrepid ...there is probably a large list of possibilities in a thesaurus for this.

This doesn't really cover hopeless because it would seem that these adjectives I listed are a natural quality of a person. It isn't really diagnosed and cured as the word hopeless suggests.

You may have to write it out, as an adverb + adjective to create this effect:

He was an incurably/a hopelessly brave man.

Comment: Who down votes and doesn't leave an explanation? At least have the courtesy to point out my fault.

Comment: If there wasn't a 'Be Nice' policy, I would say this is a trigger happy coward.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer David. I'm aiming for that sort of feeling one gets when fighting a losing battle. A deranged abandon, in some hopeless endeavor. Resignation to failure but without fear. It was probably Jo Bedard who downvoted you ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Quixotic

Per the [Wordsmyth](http://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=quixotic):

> *Exceedingly idealistic; unrealistic and impractical.*

Comment: Thanks Dan Bron. Quixotic is great to describe a person who has these qualities simultaneously, but it doesn't fit the bill.

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about a mindset, maybe ***still*** could be what you are looking for? I think it can incorporate fearlessness and hopelessness, but only if they are also at peace with the situation they are in. How because there is no more stress, it is actually a relief, even if it means death since there is nothing more to be afraid of.

***still*** - undisturbed or tranquil; silent and calm;

"I know I will die today and that its unavoidable, yet it only gives me energy to fight. So I continue on in a deranged fearlessness, abandoning myself to the endeavor. Having resigned myself to losing everything, and broken loose from any fear of loss. *I am **still**.*"

Comment: if you downvote - comment why. secondly, downvoting is for answers that are not helpful or detract from the conversation. if this isn't the best answer or your favorite, just leave it alone.